# sagemaker Monitoring 'describe processing job' Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, containers, monitoring, amazon-sagemaker

I am following the steps in the SageMaker Monitoring Tutorial here: https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_model_monitor/introduction/SageMaker-ModelMonitoring.html

And I get the following error for `sage.describe_processing job()`:

[image]

I am not using any directory as `/opt/ml...` in my code. What is the `/opt/ml...` directory mentioned in the error? And how can I fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

To be answer your question, please share the code you are using( link seems to be broken). I'm sharing code on running and creating a processing job to setup model monitoring for reference. Using this code you can run the processing job manually( without having to wait for the model monitoring job to run on an hourly basis) as long as your adhere to the API contracts
Reference [code](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop/blob/main/labs/05_model_monitor/monitoringjob_utils.py)

```
from sagemaker.processing import Processor

processor = Processor(
    base_job_name='nlp-data-drift-bert-v1',
    role=role,
    image_uri=processing_repository_uri,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.large',
    env={ 'THRESHOLD':'0.5','bucket': bucket },
)

processor.run(
    [ProcessingInput(
        input_name='endpointdata',
        source=f's3://{sagemaker_session.default_bucket()}/{s3_prefix}/endpoint/data_capture',
        destination='/opt/ml/processing/input/endpoint',
    )],
    [ProcessingOutput(
        output_name='result',
        source='/opt/ml/processing/resultdata',
        destination=destination,
    )],
)
```